# Directory "javascript" is being completely ignored

Tags: javascript, apache, ubuntu

Good Afternoon,

I am having a very specific problem with my Apache2/Ubuntu Setup, essentially, whenever I attempt to use "javascript" as a directory name, everything inside the folder is essentially ignored and when scripts or humans try to access files within the folder, they simply 404.

I have renamed the folder to "javascript2", and the files appeared. Named back to "javascript" and they disappeared when trying to navigate to them again.

I can't simply rename the folder as this is where mantis is calling, and besides, this shouldn't be happening.

Is it a reserved word? Do I have a stupid option enabled? Any suggestions / help is appreciated

Comment: What sort of "access" and "navigation" are you talking about? I can create a directory called "javascript" on my Ubuntu installation and it works perfectly well with any software I point at it.

Comment: What do the Apache error logs show?

Comment: It's not a solution, but have you tried with different browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Apache apparently, I had to comment out the following in **/etc/apache2/conf.d/javascript-common.conf**:

```
Alias /javascript /usr/share/javascript/
```

All is good now, thanks for the help anyway and hopefully this may be useful for someone else at some point!

Comment: I can confirm that this default has nothing to do with Apache. It's probably an Ubuntu customisation. It'd still be interesting to know if the Apache logs reveal whether files are been searched at `/usr/share/javascript/` (come on, there's nothing dirty in looking at log files!)